# A public action method 'cache' was not found on controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, asp.net-mvc-routing, telerik-mvc

I am getting `A public action method 'cache' was not found on controller` occasionally while executing the `actionresult`. Although here is no cache defined or used in my code.Don't know where from it is getting this. it is happening on telerik mvc grid's ajax binding. Here is the stack trace from elmah

```
HTTP Referrer
/mycontroller/75/myaction
Path Info
/mycontroller/cache/b19858cce4adf72d090c2334d5584f06
```

StackTrace

```
    System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'cache' was not found on controller 'myapp.Controllers.MyController'.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Very interesting, this is probably a good one to post in their forum, it looks like they may have a bug in the JS code for their grid

Comment: Please add your Ajax Action code

Answer (score 5):

There is a Chrome bug that matches this description: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132059
According to the issue description it does not occur with other browsers so it is very likely that Chrome has to do something with it. However, the bug is not confirmed yet and there are multiple theories what might cause it. I would suggest that you test with multiple browsers yourself to check if it is related to Chrome.